# Why does qrcode.js function take a url as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code to generate a qr code and save the base 64 code of the image as a string then display it to the console.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div class="qr-display">
    <h1>QR Code generator</h1>
    <div id="qrcode-container">
      <div id="qrcode" class="qrcode"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        generateQRCode();
      });
      function generateQRCode() {
        let website = "www.webisora.com";
        if (website) {
          let qrcodeContainer = document.getElementById("qrcode");
          qrcodeContainer.innerHTML = "";
          var qrcode = new QRCode(qrcodeContainer, website);
          document.getElementById("qrcode-container").style.display = "block";
        }
      }
      function getImageCode(){
        var src = $('#qrcode img').attr('src')
        console.log(src)
      }
      let timer = setTimeout(getImageCode, 100);
    </script>
</div>
```

The QRCode function takes a website url as a a parameter (In this case I used [www.webisora.com](http://www.webisora.com)). What is the point of this url? How does it affect how the qr code in generated? It was able to generate with every URL I tried and I didn't notice a difference.

I tried looking through the github documentation but it does not explain the purpose of this parameter.

Comment: looking at the code you presented. the Website gets converted into the QR code. Its the content of the code. So if you scan the QR code you should getthe website you encoded into it. So just replace the webasite with anything you want and the QRCode will contain that data(as long as it fits QRCodes size limitations).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can encode any string you want as a QR code, it doesn't have to be a URL. It should take you a minute or two to test that if you have a phone with a code reader.

Comment: It does not need to be a website specifically. I t can be any textual content that needs to be embedded in the QR code. And when an application that can read the QR code, scans it, it can retrieve this embedded data.

Comment: Based on your question. Id like to ask. Do you even know what a QRCode is and what is its purpose?